# How to make static and scrolling elements in silverlight for windows phone 7?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

How to make static and scrolling elements  in silverlight for windows phone 7 .

I use the following code but some issue with static component ,ie static component also scroll

my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="700"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
            <Image Source="top_1.png"></Image>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPane2" Grid.Row="2">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Image Source="down_1.png"></Image>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

The Grid.Row property is 0-based. You need to change your xaml to the following:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0"> 
    <Image Source="top_1.png"></Image> 
</Grid> 
<Grid x:Name="ContentPane2" Grid.Row="1"> 
    <ScrollViewer> 
        <Image Source="down_1.png"></Image> 
    </ScrollViewer> 
</Grid>
```